# How to fire a button click event from JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How do I fire a server side button click event from JavaScript?

I tried like this:

```
document.getElementById("<%= ButtonID.ClientID %>").click();
```

But no use. How can I do it?

Answer (score 46):

You can just place this line in a JavaScript function:

```
__doPostBack('btnSubmit','OnClick');
```

Or do something like this:

```
$('#btnSubmit').trigger('click');
```

Comment: does this line call the server side event?

Comment: @Boomer  chck this link : http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/08/some-tricks-for-asynchronous-postback.html

Comment: @pratapk can you update that comment link (maybe add to answer) I am interested and it's dead.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the second example needs jQuery and that ASP Net Forms never generates such nice ids.

Answer (score 23):

```
var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnClearSession.ClientID %>");
clickButton.click();
```

That solution works for me, but remember it wont work if your asp button has

> Visible="False"

To hide button that should be triggered with that script you should hide it with `<div hidden></div>`

Comment: Really appreciated, no one mentioned any of above will not work in Visible='False'. The <div hidden></div> worked great for me. Cheers..:)

Comment: style="display:none;" directly on the button works too.

Answer (score 16):

I used the below JavaScript code and it works...

```
var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= btnClearSession.ClientID %>");
clickButton.click();
```

Comment: it's not working for me. the page refreshes but the code never run the code behind

Answer (score 7):

None of the solutions posted here would work for me, this was my eventual solution to the problem.

```
// In Server Side code
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.GetPostBackEventReference(hiddenButton);
}

// Javascript
function SetSaved() {
    __doPostBack("<%= hiddenButton.UniqueID %>", "OnClick");
}

// ASP
 <asp:Button ID="hiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="btnSaveGroup_Click" Visible="false"/>
```

Comment: Visible="false" this is why it is not working, just hide it with <div hidden></div>

Comment: Looking back on this - what we really needed to do was use an Ajax call to a server side function rather than relying on WebForms.

Answer (score 3):

I lived this problem in two days and suddenly I realized it that I am using this click method(for asp button) in a submit button(in html submit button) javascript method...

I mean ->

I have an html submit button and an asp button like these:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Siparişi Gönder" onclick="SendEmail()" />
<asp:Button ID="sendEmailButton" runat="server" Text="Gönder" OnClick="SendToEmail" Visible="True"></asp:Button>
```

SendToEmail() is a server side method in Default.aspx
SendEmail() is a javascript method like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
   function SendEmail() {
            document.getElementById('<%= sendEmailButton.UniqueID %>').click();
            alert("Your message is sending...");
        }
</script>
```

And this "document.getElementById('<%= sendEmailButton.UniqueID %>').click();" method did not work in just Crome. It was working in IE and Firefox.

Then I tried and tried a lot of ways for executing "SendToEmail()" method in Crome.

Then suddenly I changed html submit button --> just html button like this and now it is working:

```html
<input type="button" value="Siparişi Gönder" onclick="SendEmail()" />
```

Have a nice days...

Answer (score 1):

I can make things work this way:

inside javascript junction that is executed by the html button:

`document.getElementById("<%= Button2.ClientID %>").click();`

ASP button inside div:

```
<div id="submitBtn" style="display: none;">
   <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="AllValidators" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
</div>
```

Everything runs from the .cs file except that the code below doesn't execute. There is no message box and redirect to the same page (refresh all boxes):

```
 int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 if (count > 0)
 {
   cmd2.CommandText = insertSuperRoster;
   cmd2.Connection = con;
   cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
   string url = "VaccineRefusal.aspx";
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "callfunction", "alert('Data Inserted Successfully!');window.location.href = '" + url + "';", true);
  }
```

Any ideas why these lines won't execute?

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was the validation group that was not specified.
I added ValidationGroup="none" as per below and it worked.

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnQuickSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" 
OnClick="BtnQuickSearch_Click" ValidationGroup="none" />
```

I must mention that I had 2 other forms with buttons on the page, both had their own validation groups specified. This button had did not have a validation group specified and the onclick event simply did not fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill a hidden field from your JavaScript code and do an explicit postback from JavaScript. Then from the server side, check that hiddenfield and do whatever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.FormName.btnSubmit.click();
```

works for me. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#"+document.getElementById("<%= ButtonID.ClientID %>")).trigger("click");
```