# Using vb.net code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

usually when I programming a web application with java I use DWR library to enables Java on the server and JavaScript in a browser to interact and call each other.

for example, I can call a java routine to access the DB directly from a javascript code, and this is really useful.

Now I'm trying to create a web application with visual studio 2012 and I don't know if I can do the same thing with asp.net.

I've tried some "googling" but i don't had success.
Someone can help me?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english >.<

Comment: Are you developing MVC or Webform ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the server side code by using javaScript.

There are some good links on this [site](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/197815/Calling-VB-NET-Function-into-Javascript-Code).

Based on my experience, i found this web service to be a very useful tool.


1. You must have a [web service or asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). (check how to create [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms464040%28v=office.14%29.aspx)).
2. Use jQuery or other method of Ajax POST to communicate with the web service.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/location_of_your_webservice/ASMX_FILE.asmx/backend_method_or_function",
    ...
```

Or if you just have to fire a button click that triggers the backend event then you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646162/how-to-fire-a-button-click-event-from-javascript-in-asp-net).