# Trigger both 'onClick' and 'onClientClick' event on an ASP button from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, onclick, onclientclick

I'm working on an existing code and came across a ASP button which has a onClick and onClientClick event on it.

I'm trying to generate a click event from an external Javascript file so that both the events are triggered.

I'm using the below line to achive it-

```
document.getElementById("ID_ReleaseUserAuthPending_okBtn").click();
```

But the OnClientClick event is being triggered as expected, but the onClick event isn't. i.e., The Javascript method is being processed, but the onClick() in the C# codebehind isn't.

Please help me out if there is any way where I can call the onClick event too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a return false statement in your on client click js function which is stopping further code execution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fire a button click event from JavaScript in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646162/how-to-fire-a-button-click-event-from-javascript-in-asp-net)

Comment: Hi @Amit No there is a 'return true' statement. The process flows when directly clicked, but doesn't when triggered from JS.

Comment: Hi @BWA thanks for the reply, but I have tried the approach suggested in the link shared. They don't seem to help us in this scenario

Comment: can you post your js function code?

Comment: @AbhishekK. Sorry, too big to post here. :(

Comment: may be before reaching at the end of js function there may be return false; or somehow the return true statement is not being executed. put an alert just before return true and check if it's being executed.

Comment: Lemme try checking it @Abhishek :)

Comment: @theLearner maybe something block postback to serverside. Check postback existance and data in postback.

Answer (score 1):

From the client click function, from js, call
__dopostback. That is underscore underscore do post back. You can google it for sample code.
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/667531/dopostback-function

Answer (score 0):

At the end of javascript method put

```
return true;
```

statement.

It should work.

Comment: It is returned as true @abhishek . The code works fine when directly clicked on the button. The issue is faced when triggered from JS