# Calling a button click function using javascript in c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Hi I am trying to call a button click function written within the c# code behind from javascript. but its not triggering the button click function. I didnt find anything suspicious in the code. Please check and let me know what is actually blocking the call. These are my code scraps.

```
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function ConfirmFuncn() {
            var Msge = document.getElementById('<%=hdnMsge.ClientID %>').value;
            if (confirm(Msge)) {
                document.getElementById('<%=hdnTestValue.ClientID %>').value = "true";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('<%=hdnTestValue.ClientID %>').value = "false";
            }

            document.getElementById('<%=btnSaveHidden.ClientID %>').Click();
        }
    </script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSaveHidden" runat="server" Visible="false" 
                            Text="HiddenSaveButton" onclick="btnSaveHidden_Click"
                             />
```

Here it does not call `btnSaveHidden_Click`. Javascript function `ConfirmFuncn` is calling properly, because i am getting the message value I set to hidden field. But `btnSaveHidden_Click` is not triggering. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fire a button click event from JavaScript in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646162/how-to-fire-a-button-click-event-from-javascript-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

it wont work when:

```
Visible="False"
```

incited of hidden the button by it self just hide in indies a hidden div :

you can hide your button with hidden div

```
<div style="display: none;">    
    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveHidden" runat="server" Visible="false" 
                Text="HiddenSaveButton" onclick="btnSaveHidden_Click" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="display: none;"` instead of `Visible="false"`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveHidden" runat="server" style="display: none;"     
            Text="HiddenSaveButton" onclick="btnSaveHidden_Click" />
```