# Triggering click event in javascript works, but actual asp.net event is not fired

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a image on which I am opening an alert. On confirmation in this alert, I am triggering the server click event. Here is a quick piece of code.

```
function showConfirmMessage() {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this data!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: true
    }, function () {
        document.getElementById("btnDeleteUser").click();
    });
    return false;
}
```

Here is the code of the button.

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteUser" ClientIDMode="Static" class="hidden" type="submit" OnClick="btnDeleteUser_Click" />
```

`document.getElementById("btnDeleteUser").click();` this line is called successfully when I click confirm in the alert box. But the actual event is never fired. The page is never submitted back to the server.

I am unable to figure out what is missing here. There are no errors in the console. Application never reaches the server side function.

Comment: Have you checked those solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646162/how-to-fire-a-button-click-event-from-javascript-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

you should use it:

```
document.getElementById("<%= btnDeleteUser.ClientID %>").click();
```

Comment: we can't use above code because i am using btnDeleteUser inside javascript file.

Comment: aspx:
window.DeleteUserClientId = "<%= btnDeleteUser.ClientID %>";

js: 
document.getElementById(window.DeleteUserClientId).click();